# adding image src from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

My question is why doesn't the image appear on my php page, i have image url in database under 'imageurl'. I want to echo url to image src and this will show the picture from the folder. The error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in .... on line 95. I will put the line 95 in the sample code too.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
         <div class="NewsItem">
            <div>
              <h1><?php echo $row['txt']; ?></a> <br>
              <span>posted on <?php echo $row['added']; ?></span><span> by <?php echo $row['adder'];?></span>

             </div>
             <div class="imgdiv"><?php if(($row['imageurl'] == 'NULL') or ($row['imageurl']== '')){
                 //No images
             }
             else{
            Line 95----  <img src="<?php echo $row['imageurl'];?>" width='300' height='300'/>
             }

             ?></div>
             <br>
             <div>
             <form action="comment.php"method="post" name="addComment"><input type="text" placeholder="kommentaar" name="commenttext" maxlenght="100"><input type="submit" name="addComment" value="Lisa kommentaar">
             <input id="prodId3" name="prodId3" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
             </form>
             </div>
          </div>

      <?php 
      endwhile;
      ?>
```

Comment: most likely the URL provided can't be resolved by the server. Inspect the HTML source code to find out what's actually there and if that makes sense in HTTP context.

Comment: I just added to HTML output to code.

Comment: start and end php after else and if condition

Comment: @M.Kesküll, are you following the answers below?

Comment: Yes, i did. I got the answer from below. I accepted answer from Oulalahakabu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget about printing the result after your elseif clause. Moreover, you should [use alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in PHP template, it will make things easier to read/maintain (You did it for while/endwhile).

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
 <div class="NewsItem">
    <div>
      <h1><?php echo $row['txt']; ?></a> <br>
      <span>posted on <?php echo $row['added']; ?></span><span> by <?php echo $row['adder'];?></span>

     </div>
     <div class="imgdiv">
    <?php if(($row['imageurl'] == 'NULL') or ($row['imageurl']== '')): ?>
        No image
    <?php else: ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['imageurl'];?>" width='300' height='300'/>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
     <br>
     <div>
     <form action="comment.php"method="post" name="addComment"><input type="text" placeholder="kommentaar" name="commenttext" maxlenght="100"><input type="submit" name="addComment" value="Lisa kommentaar">
     <input id="prodId3" name="prodId3" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
     </form>
     </div>
  </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Someone calling me, done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Need to maintain php tags open and close at line #95

So,
Change your `else` part like this:

```
else{ ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $row['imageurl'];?>" width='300' height='300'/>
<?php    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is missmatch of opening and closing php tag, also put full URL of image with site URL 
Try the following code

```
else{ ?>
      <img src="<?php echo "your site url".$row['imageurl'];?>" width='300' height='300'/>
<?php    }
```

Comment: Why should he try it? Explain what was wrong in the original code, and how you fixed it.